# Is there a plain Android SDK animator that executes a task in intervals?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to find the simplest solution for a simple task: blinking item on a View (hide/show in every second). But the solution I found seems to be a bit over-complicated.

I cannot use a Timer/TimerTask pair, because that leads to an exception for trying to access a View from a different thread.

The only solution I found was like:

```
package com.my.package;

import android.animation.ValueAnimator;
import android.view.View;
... other imports ...

public class MyView extends View {
    private ValueAnimator myAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 2);
    private boolean itemVisible;

    ... all constructors are calling the init() method ...

    init() {
        myAnimator.setDuration(1000);
        myAnimator.addListener(new MyAnimatorListener(this));
        myAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
        myAnimator.start();
    }

    private class MyAnimatorListener implements ValueAnimator.AnimatorListener {
        private MyView myView;

        MyAnimatorListener(MyView myView) {
            this.myView = myView;
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animator) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animator) { }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animator) {
            myView.toggleItemVisibility();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animator) { }
    }

    public void toggleItemVisibility() {
        itemVisible = !itemVisible;

        invalidate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        ...

        if (itemVisible) {
            ... draw item ...
        }

        ...
    }
}
```

The problems with this are:

- I had to define a change interval `ValueAnimator.ofInt(0, 2)` even though this won't be used for anything. I'm only tapping to the `repeat` event. (I can't use the `update` event, because that would be called for every frame, even when the value doesn't change.)
- One has to override a lot of methods: start/cancel/end, but only the `repeat` is used.

Is there a more simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a `Handler` to post a `Runnable` which then posts itself recursively using `postDelayed`.
Something along the following lines should work,

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myView.toggleItemVisibility();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
handler.postDelayed(runnable, 1000);
```